# How to configure Spring XD modules using ModuleConfiguration.java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd

I have created a Spring XD module, in the likeness of the example tweet transformer. The Spring docs say that you can either use a `spring-module.properties` and `spring-module.xml` configuration under `src/main/resources/config/` or a dedicated `ModuleConfiguration.java` file, which defines a Bean. However, if I only use the latter it won't run. XD complains that it cannot determine the module type.

If I add the `spring-modules.properties` and the module xml, it works. My `ModuleConfiguration.java` looks like this:

```
package mypackage;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class ModuleConfiguration {
    @Bean
    MessageChannel input() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    @Bean
    MessageChannel output() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    MyTransformer transformer() {
        return new MyTransformer();
    }
}
```

My pom.xml inherits from the spring module pom:

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.xd</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-xd-module-parent</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
   <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

The Transformer looks like this:

```
package mypackage;

import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessageEndpoint;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer;

@MessageEndpoint
public class MyTransformer
{

   @Transformer( inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "output" )
   public String transform( String payload )
   {
     return "Test";
   }
}
```

Comment: Please Show your MyTransformer code

Comment: It's `spring-module.properties`, not `spring-modules.properties`.  No **s**.

Comment: @heenenee typo, corrected

Comment: @Arne @shazin is that the reason that your `base_packages` as specified in shazin's answer is not getting picked up?

Comment: @heenenee No, the actual source uses the correct name (`spring-module.properties`) I just mistyped it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `src/main/resources/config/spring-modules.properties` add the following.

```
base_packages=mypackage
```

This will enable the ModuleConfiguration to be picked up by the Spring XD Engine and which will in turn load your custom Transformer `MyTransformer`.

Everything else looks good.

Comment: I have that line in my properties file. Will try again if this is indeed enough.

Comment: I checked, and I can now configure everything by using the Java annotations! Great, thanks!